# Making sense of Goedel's First Incompleteness Theorem

Tags: logic, incompleteness

In Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy they say that (for a formal system F) by the Diagonalization Lemma a sentence G can be constructed: $F \vdash G_F$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉)$. This sentence G basically says that F proves $G_F$ iff the Goedelnumber of $G_F$ is not provable.

If I assume G then I can totally follow them on why neither $G_F$ nor $\lnot G_F$ is not provable, but my problem is this: why do I have to assume G, what if I just assume ~G? Then the whole problem resolves and everything seems fine because ~G $ \equiv$ $(F \vdash G_F$ $\land$ $Prov(⌈G_F⌉))$ $\lor$ $ (\lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉) \land F\nvdash G_F)$.

Comment: It seems you misread $F\vdash G_F\leftrightarrow\neg Prov(\lceil G_F\rceil)$  as $[F\vdash G_F]\leftrightarrow\neg Prov(\lceil G_F\rceil)$ when in fact it is $F\vdash [G_F\leftrightarrow\neg Prov(\lceil G_F\rceil)]$.  The point is that $F\vdash G_F$ would be a statement in the metalanguage, not a formula in the formal system $F$, so it can't be combined by $\leftrightarrow$ with another formula from $F$.

Comment: "neither GF nor ¬GF is not provable" Shouldn't it be "neither GF nor ¬GF is provable"?

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstood: $G$ is not the biconditional $(F \vdash G_F) \leftrightarrow (\lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉))$. Rather, $G$ is the *metalogical* claim that the biconditional $G_F$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉)$ (which is a logical claim) can be proven in $F$. And that metalogical claim we write as $F \vdash G_F \leftrightarrow \lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉)$ (think of it as $F \vdash (G_F \leftrightarrow \lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉))$

Moreover, it is not claim $G$ that is what is typically referred to as the 'Godel sentence', but rather $G_F$. That is, Godel's proof shows that relative to any 'strong enough' (strong enough to prove elementary arithmetical truths basically), consistent, and recursive formal system $F$, there must be some sentence $G_F$ such that $F \vdash G_F$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉)$ is the case.  When you now assume that $G_F$ is false, you get a problem, because then, given the truth of the biconditional (it's true since $F$ derives it), it would have to be true that $G_F$ is provable, and thus true, which contradicts the assumption that is was false. So, it must be true. And, given that same biconditional, not provable.

The truth of $G$ itself is not under discussion. Godel's proof that $G$ has to be the case.

Comment: Ok, I see. But how does Goedel arrive to $F \vdash (G_F \leftrightarrow \lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉))$? I mean he can _construct_ the sentence $G_F \leftrightarrow \lnot Prov(⌈G_F⌉)$ in F because of the Diagonalization Lemma, but how can he know that this very sentence also follows ($\vdash$) from F?

Comment: @Pippen That's exactly what the diagonal lemma says: that there is a sentence with the desired property.

Comment: @Pippen Good question ... and you're exactly right that the Diagonal Lemma is behind it.  Let me see if I remember ...... . Wait, Noah said it well: the Diagonal Lemma is a meta-logical Lemma that proves something about the proving abilities of F

Comment: @Bram28 No, it's not a logical tautology, but this $F$-sequent is exactly what the diagonal lemma gives. DL says "For any formula $\varphi$ there is some sentence $\theta$ such that $F\vdash\theta\leftrightarrow\varphi(\ulcorner\underline{\theta}\urcorner))$." Here we're taking $\varphi$ to be $\neg Prov$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, OK!  Well, I don't blame Pippen for being confused. After many years, I am still fuzzy on the details :P  Thx!

Comment: @Bram28 Oh neither do I, this stuff can be quite confusing!

Answer (score 4):

The diagonal lemma isn't used to construct what you call $G$, but rather $G_F$. Really, we should ignore $G$ altogether and just focus on what's going on "inside $F$."

- EDIT: actually, it's even worse than that! [The article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#FirIncTheCom) uses $G$ ambiguously to refer to both the *sentence* $G_F\leftrightarrow Prov_F(\underline{\ulcorner G_F\urcorner})$ (note that the article also omits the numeralization here!) and the *sequent* $F\vdash G_F\leftrightarrow Prov_F(\underline{\ulcorner G_F\urcorner})$ (look at the first appearance of $(G)$). I'm normally a fan of SEP, but in my opinion this is a situation where this kind of minor sloppiness is a really bad idea.

---

To start with, let's state the diagonal lemma precisely. For $F$ an "appropriate" system the diagonal lemma says the following:

> For every formula $\varphi$ there is some sentence $\theta$ such that $$F\vdash\theta\leftrightarrow\varphi(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner}).$$

Here "$\ulcorner\psi\urcorner$" is the Godel number of a sentence $\psi$  and "$\underline{n}$" is the numeral corresponding to $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So the diagonal lemma is really doing two things: given a formula $\varphi$, it produces a particular sentence **and** a particular $F$-proof.

This may seem rather mysterious until you read the proof of the diagonal lemma in detail to see how the desired sentence $\theta$ and $F$-proof of $\theta\leftrightarrow\varphi(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner})$ are constructed from a given $\varphi$. It's quite concrete, but tedious and often opaque at first glance.

In the incompleteness theorem, then, we apply the diagonal lemma with $\neg Prov$ as our $\varphi$. (Well, at first - we later use [Rosser's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick) to get a different choice of $\varphi$ that works even better.)

---

A couple quick comments:

- "Produces" is a good word to use above: the diagonal lemma is totally constructive.
- Meanwhile, the diagonal lemma doesn't tell us that $\theta$ **literally is** $\varphi(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner})$, but merely that $\theta$ and $\varphi(\underline{\ulcorner\theta\urcorner})$ are $F$-equivalent. That said, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83155/can-we-find-strong-fixed-points-in-the-fixed-point-lemma-of-g%C3%B6dels-incompletene).

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with the advice of ignoring $G$ the way that SEP article defines it!  Ooh, 'F-equivalent' .. that makes sense now! I've always thought about this as 'arithmetical equivaklence' ... but we're really talking about '[some theory]-equivalence', right?

Comment: @Bram28 I normally really like them but I think they dropped the ball here: they bring up the equivalence as a separate object but then treat it sloppily and name it confusingly.